# Select records based on previous group

Tags: sql, mysql

For the [following table](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vYuAyH28N629bvKY4bfQgi/1) named example is it possible in MySQL to make a query that returns a result like the table named result?

The records are ordered by `col1`, I want in the `col2` when there is a bigger number all the records after should have that number, until there is another bigger one and so on...

So in the above example: record id 5,7 should show 10 instead of 1 in `col2` and record id 10 should show 20 instead of 10 in `col2`.

I can probably achieve looping through all records (in php or js), but I was wondering if it would be possible in MySql and if maybe is more efficient than looping.

Comment: Providing data instead of images of it helps to get much faster recommendations from the community.it is one of the reasons that you get Downvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT example.id,
       example.col1,
       @current := GREATEST(@current, col2) col2
FROM example
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT @current := MIN(col2)
  FROM example ) get_min_value
ORDER BY example.col1
```

| id | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 11 | 10 |
| 4 | 12 | 10 |
| 5 | 15 | 10 |
| 6 | 20 | 10 |
| 7 | 21 | 10 |
| 8 | 22 | 20 |
| 9 | 25 | 20 |
| 10 | 26 | 20 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6N0D0eHD)

PS. "*The records are ordered by `col1`*" - this column is not defined as unique, so it may contain duplicates. In this case you must define additional ordering criteria and expand ORDER BY clause accordingly, if not then the output will be non-deterministic.